# Managing nested loops or loop with lapply

Tags: r, events, analysis

my question may seem trivial but I can not get a solution.
I have a list containing 5 dataframes named by stock (my real list contains 250 stocks).
Each dataframe has the same number and name of columns:

1. Date: time series formatted as character
2. returns: time series of stock returns
3. DJSTOXX: time series of index returns
4. EPS: Earnings announcement dates, which contains also NAs, formatted as characters.

For each dataframe I would like to run the `evReturn` function from the `erer`package, which returns a list with different measures regarding cumulative abnormal returns around certain dates. The main inputs of the function are **y** which should be a dataframe, containing a column for dates (time series), a column with returns, a column with index returns and a column with the earning announcement dates. As you can see below, this code run for the firm **NESN** the event analysis for each dates where an announcement has been made. Here I set for each date in the time series equal to the EPS dates, omitting NAs, do the function `evReturn`. It saves the output in ***hh3*** which is a list where for each EPS date the event return is computed.

```
hh3 <- list()
for (i in na.omit(dflist$NESN$Date[dflist$NESN$Date == dflist$NESN$EPS])){
  hh3[[i]] <- evReturn(y = dflist$NESN, firm = "return", event.date = i, y.date = "Date",
                       index = "DJSTOXX", event.win = 2, est.win = 50, digits = 3)
}
```

Now my question is:
How can I set it in order to run this code for each stock in the list? Therefore, I am expecting the resulting list to have 5 list (1 for each stock) with a list for each EPS dates.

As you can see in the `evReturn` function I explicitly set $NESN but I want to set it as for each dataframe in ***dflist*** do the function.

I have tried with lapply the following:

```
lapply(dflist, function(x){
  for (i in na.omit(x$Date[x$Date == x$EPS])){
    dflist2[[i]] <- evReturn(y = x, firm = "return", event.date = i, y.date = "Date",
                             index = "DJSTOXX", event.win = 2, est.win = 50, digits = 3)
  }})
```

But it returns:

```
Error in xj[i] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
```

I thus tried to nest 2 loops as:

```
for(j in seq_along(dflist)){
  for (i in na.omit(dflist$j$Date[dflist$j$Date == dflist$j$EPS])){
    hh7[[j]][i] <- evReturn(y = dflist$j, firm = "return", event.date = i, y.date = "Date",
                         index = "DJSTOXX", event.win = 2, est.win = 50, digits = 3)
  }}
```

But it returns ***hh7*** as a list of length 0.

Any help is highly appreciated since it seems I am missing something.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to be sure how to help because you don't provide any sample data, but you should be able to do something like this:

```
get_ev_return <- function(d) {
  dates = na.omit(d[d$Date = d$EPS, "Date"])
  lapply(dates, \(date) {
    evReturn(y=d,firm="return", event_date=date, y.date = "Date", index="DJSTOXX", event.win=2, est.win=50, digits=3)
  })
}

lapply(dflist, get_ev_return)
```

Before running the `lapply()`, test `get_ev_return()` on `NESN`, and see if it works for one frame.  Also, you'll need to check that `dates` within the `get_ev_return()` function contains any dates.. Maybe you have one or more data.frames where there are no rows where `Date` == `EPS`....  Again, this is the problem with not providing any sample data in your question.

Comment: Langtang, your code is correct. For data.frames with NAs the code does the right job by not running the ***evReturn*** function but it skips to the next dataframes. Thank you a lot, I wasn't able to think about 2 lapply. :) Ps: apologies to not add data but I was restricted by the number of characters.